# how to make a copy of a mysql table, adding some columns and taking some out, changing the order and retaining any data relevant to the new table?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want a wordpress user to be able to alter the structure of a database table, while retaining data in columns that are unchanged.

My strategy so far has been to:

1. Create a new table called table_temp with the new structure.
2. For each of the columns from the old table that exist in the new table, loop
   through the rows of the old table and insert values into the new
   table column.
3. Drop the old table and rename the new table as the old
   table.

Step 2 is where I go wrong so I have not bothered with step 3 yet.  The first column works fine, but the values being inserted into the second retained column begin at the row following the last value inserted in the first.

```
function update_table($_POST) {
global $wpdb;

//collect the updated table's metadata from the $_POST


$slug = $_POST[slug].'_temp';
$WB_table = $_POST[slug];
unset($_POST[slug]);
unset($_POST[tblAppendGrid_rowOrder]);
unset($_POST[status]);

// create the new temp table
$wpdb->query("
CREATE TABLE $slug (
     id INT (6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
");

//remove reference to the old meta in WB_table _meta
$wpdb->delete( 'WB_table_meta', array( 'WB_table' => $WB_table ) );

// add the new meta to WB_table _meta
// loop through the $_POST array
for($i=1;$i<=count($_POST)/5;$i++) {

// pull the array elemnts from $_POST
$name = $_POST['tblAppendGrid_name_'.$i];
$display = $_POST['tblAppendGrid_display_'.$i];
$type = $_POST['tblAppendGrid_type_'.$i];
$maxlength = $_POST['tblAppendGrid_maxlength_'.$i];
$width = $_POST['tblAppendGrid_width_'.$i];

// Add column names to the new table
$wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE ".$slug." ADD ".$name." text(160)");

// Add meta to WB_table_meta
$wpdb->insert('WB_table_meta',
               array(
                     'WB_table' => $WB_table,
                     'name' => $name,
                     'display' => $display,
                     'type' => $type,
                     'maxlength' => $maxlength,
                     'width' => $width),
               array('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%d','%d')
               );

//copy data to the new table from the old table if the column exists in the new table

if ($wpdb->query("SELECT ".$name." from ".$WB_table."", A_ARRAY) == true) {
     $rows = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ".$name." from ".$WB_table."");

        foreach($rows as $row){
        $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $slug ($name) VALUES ('$row')");
        $wpdb->show_errors();

        } //for each

} // if

} // for loop

} // function update_table
```

The new table created looks as shown below, however it should only have two rows.

```
14  kitchen NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
15  kitchen NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
16  NULL    laundry NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
17  NULL    laundry NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
18  NULL    NULL    office  NULL    NULL    NULL
19  NULL    NULL    office  NULL    NULL    NULL
20  NULL    NULL    NULL    8:00    NULL    NULL
21  NULL    NULL    NULL    8:00    NULL    NULL
22  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8:10    NULL
23  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8:10    NULL
24  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8:15
25  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8:15
```

Comment: I guess there are worse ideas out there. Can't think of one off hand.

Comment: Why don't you use simply [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html) followed by renaming tables? If you want to create the table separately you could use [INSERT INTO ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html). It's much easier and less error prone.

Comment: Because giving users the ability to alter the structure of a database table is a bad idea. They'll just break it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks VMai.  Your suggestion worked great.  Following code resulted in a new table with the correct fields.

```
// build the column string
if ($wpdb->query("SELECT ".$name." from ".$WB_table."", A_ARRAY) == true) {
     $cols .= $name.',';
     } // if
} // for loop


$col = substr($cols, 0, -1);

//copy data to the new table from the old table if the column exists in the new table
$wpdb->query("
     INSERT INTO ".$slug."
     (".$col.")
     SELECT ".$col."
     FROM ".$WB_table."
     ");
     $wpdb->show_errors();
```